# Gatsby's `navigate` function to navigate to the same page?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

Is it possible to use Gatsby's `navigate` function to navigate to the same page?

For instance, I built a search component that lives on the navigation bar, therefor accessible on any page. Once users perform search, they get routed to the Search Results page via `navigate(/search-results)`.

If they are on that page, and want to perform the search again, that `navigate` function does not work, hence no results display.

I'm aware I could do a `window.location.reload()` but wanted to see if there are other ways.

Answer (score 2):

Gatsby's navigation (`Link` component or `navigate` function) doesn't support parameters *per se* as you want to.

From [Gatsby's docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-link/#recommendations-for-programmatic-in-app-navigation):

> Neither `<Link>` nor navigate can be used for in-route navigation with a
> hash or query parameter. If you need this behavior, you should either
> use an anchor tag or import the `@reach/router` package—which Gatsby
> already depends upon—to make use of its navigate function, like so:

So, that said, you have two approaches:

- Importing the navigation from `@reach/router`:

  ```
  import { navigate } from '@reach/router';


    onClick = () => {
      navigate('?foo=bar');
    }
  ```
- Using `window.location` as you pointed

Of course, the `@reach/router` will give you a smoother workaround.